# Downgrade MySQL 6.x to 5.x

Tags: mysql

How can I downgrade my MySQL database from version 6 to 5? Since I manage to install some packages only support to ver 5.

Comment: What's the environment you're working with?

Comment: AppServ 2.6.0

    Apache 2.2.8
    PHP 6.0.0-dev
    MySQL 6.0.4-alpha
    phpMyAdmin-2.10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be trying a dump & restore.  As long as you didn't use any MySQL 6.x functionality, it should go smoothly.

As always, backup before doing potentially dangerous actions.

Comment: Thanks! However, I am just a starter. My webserver starts programming from 6.x, that is why asking such issue.